# using facets on every column with color grouping

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I've seen a lot of people use facets to visualize data. I want to be able to run this on every column in my dataset and then have it grouped by some categorical value within each individual plot.

I've seen others use `gather()` to plot histogram or densities.  I can do that ok, but I guess I fundamentally misunderstand how to use this technique.

I want to be able to do just what I have below - but when I have it grouped by a category.  For example, histogram of every column but stacked by the value `color`.  Or dual density plots of every column with these two lines of different colors.

I'd like this - but instead of clarity it is every single column like this...

```
library(tidyverse)

# what I want but clarity should be replaced with every column except FILL
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = price, fill = color)) +
  geom_histogram(position = 'stack') +
  facet_wrap(clarity~.)

# it would look exactly like this, except it would have the fill value by a group.
gathered_data = gather(diamonds %>% select_if(is.numeric))

ggplot(gathered_data , aes(value)) +
  geom_histogram() + 
  theme_classic() +
  facet_wrap(~key, scales='free')
```

Comment: Can you draw your expected output in Paint or Word/PPT and post it here? It's easier to help

Comment: This throws an error: `gather(diamonds %>% select_if(is.numeric)) )`

Comment: @Tung This is an example of what I am after except that it applies to every column.   **ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, color=Species))+geom_density()**    Obviously this can be applied to histogram like I have above.   I want this sort of logic applied to every column.

Answer (score 0):

`tidyr::gather` needs four pieces:

1) data (in this case `diamonds`, passed through the pipe into the first parameter of `gather` below)

2) key

3) value

4) names of the columns that will be converted to key / value pairs.

```
gathered_data <- diamonds %>% 
  gather(key, value, 
         select_if(diamonds, is.numeric) %>% names())
```

Comment: understood.   Maybe I'm missing it, but see my comment above.  I want something like this **ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, color=Species))+geom_density()**    I want to be able to do a double graph by color / categorical value  with every column (numerical) as its own facet plot

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you are looking for. A picture of your expected output would have been much more illuminating than a description (not all of us are native English speakers...), but perhaps something like this?

```
diamonds %>% 
  rename(group = color) %>% # change this line to use another categorical 
                            # column as the grouping variable

  group_by(group) %>%       # select grouping variable + all numeric variables
  select_if(is.numeric) %>%
  ungroup() %>%

  tidyr::gather(key, value, -group) %>% # gather all numeric variables

  ggplot(aes(x = value, fill = group)) +
  geom_histogram(position = "stack") + 
  theme_classic() +
  facet_wrap(~ key, scales = 'free')
```

[image: geom_histogram example]

```
# alternate example using geom density
diamonds %>% 
  rename(group = cut) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  select_if(is.numeric) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  tidyr::gather(key, value, -group) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = value, color = group)) +
  geom_density() + 
  theme_classic() +
  facet_wrap(~ key, scales = 'free')
```

[image: geom_density example]